# non responsive flexbox in medium devices

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm an intern and as part of a training exercise I had to make a flex-box checker design with a centred image in each item. But my flex items won't fill the page on medium devices and I don't know why. In the dev tool when I checked the responsiveness on iPad and iPad pro (and other medium devices) the items would't cover the page. If anyone can find my mistake I would appreciate knowing what it is. (All constructive criticism is welcomed, and thank you in advance)

[image: screen shot of what happens]

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-container {
  display: flex;
  flex 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

img {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.flex-item {
  background: purple;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* this centers the images to the center*/
  align-items: center;
}


/*  this sets all even indexed boxes to background purple*/

.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background: #8000f2;
}


/*  this overwrites the purple default background of the flex items for special even cases*/

.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ffffff;
}

footer {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  min-height: 160px;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* super small devices */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .flex-item {
    width: 101.33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="list-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="scrolltop.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="scrolltop.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="scrolltop.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="scrolltop.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="scrolltop.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="scrolltop.png"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be good to have the image also

Comment: never mind I found the error, it was a missing colon :'(